# Datas are not loading in datagridMUI when i used a json local file

Tags: reactjs, json

To display data in datagridMUI, I used https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos first and it worked.
After that, I customised the data by adding other information and saved it in the `data.json` file. The problem is that the data does not load

```
const [tasks,setTasks] = useState([]);

const fetchData = async () => {
    try{
        const jsonData= require('./data.json');
        const res = await fetch(jsonData);
        const tasksData = await res.json();

        setTasks(tasksData);
        console.log(tasksData);
    } catch(err){
        // Do something for an error here
    }
}
```

[Datas are not loading in datagridMUI when i used a json local file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmGiJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Move your `data.json` file into public folder then you can fetch that data directly writing this code:

```
const res = await fetch("data.json",
    { headers: {
'Content-Type':'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json'
}
    }
  );
```

Or you can create a js file and store the json code into a constant and export that.
Then in your component you can import it like other javascript module.